# How to remove the (.) in a string and then display every alphabetic character with a dot

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a a function who takes a string a parameter, removes the dots, loops trough every alphabetic character and display like this (A.B.C.) when input is  (A..B..C) for example.

### How can I build this function?

Here for I have the next function in mind, unfortunately is not working I get a output result like this (hfff) when input string is "h..f.ff", would like to have this output (H.F.F.F)

```
function filter (initials) {
  let result = initials.replace(/\./g, '')
  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
     result[i] + ".";
  }
  return result
  console.log(result)
}
const initials = "h..f.ff"
console.log(filter(initials))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
function filter(initials) {
  return initials.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '') // Remove non-letters
                 .toUpperCase()
                 .split('')              // Convert to an Array
                 .map(l => l + '.')      // Add dots
                 .join('');              // Join 
}

const initials = "h..f.ff";
console.log(filter(initials));
```

Comment: touche , we posted within 7 seconds of each other :'D

Comment: Yes, I saw your answer and was going to _not_ click on "Submit", but then I saw that your function was not valid (you fixed it since) so I posted mine 

Comment: Edited as requested

Comment: one more thing, how do you get that nifty `run code snippet` option?

Comment: Thanks @blex, the function is good however The last character do not get a dot (H.F.F.F)  check your output Can you modified the answer?

Comment: @Basta020 I wasn't sure the last one was needed because you posted different examples (`A.B.C.` and `H.F.F.F`). Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use `replaceAll` to remove all `.` char with nothing.

Then from that string, make all letters uppercase.

From that string, split the whole word up into and array of letters using `split` (Each piece of the string on each side of the parameter passed to `split` gets turned into an element in a new array. if you leave the parameter blank, it's just each character in the string)

Finally join each those elements together with a `.` between them using `join`

```js
function filter (initials) {
   initials=initials.replaceAll('.','');
   initials=initials.toUpperCase();
   initials=initials.split('');
   initials=initials.join('.');
   return initials;
 }

var test = "h..f..t....e.Z";
console.log(filter(test));
```

Thanks @blex for the snippet advice

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign this

```
result[i] + ".";
```

to something. Do:

```
let i,newresult;
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  newresult += result[i] + ".";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can:

1. make the string uppercase
2. split the string char-by-char
3. filter only letters
4. join using "."

```
function format(string){
    return string.toUpperCase()
             .split("")
             .filter(c => /[a-zA-Z]/.test(c))
             .join(".")
 
}
format("h..f.ff") // "H.F.F.F"
```